# DecorationBox in Jetpack Compose BasicTextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I use jetpack compose create a editText,I want to show a hint like before "android:hint",
so I try to use decorationBox,but after I created it the input isn't displayed and the log can display my input content.
this is my code,

```
val passState= remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
BasicTextField(
    decorationBox = {
        Text("password",color = loginGrayColor)
    },
    value = passState.value,
    onValueChange = { passState.value = it ; Log.d("password",it.text) },
    singleLine = true,
    maxLines = 1,
    textStyle = TextStyle(
        fontSize = 15.sp,
        color = loginInputTextColor
    ),
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(start = 10.dp, top = 10.dp)
        .height(20.dp)
)
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have to add the **`innerTextField`** provided by the `decorationBox`.
Something like:

```
var value by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
        Row(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.LightGray, RoundedCornerShape(percent = 30))
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            if (value.text.isEmpty()) {
                Text("Label")
            }
            innerTextField()  //<-- Add this
        }
    },
)
```

If you would like to have the cursor start at the beginning of the placeholder label, put the `decorationBox` content inside a `Box` rather than a `Row`.

Comment: Put the decorationBox content inside a Box rather than a Row if you would like to have the cursor start at the beginning of the placeholder label

Comment: @CharlesWoodson 1 year later I need to thank you, you saved my day !

Comment: @nkayou glad to help, please upvote my question and the answer if you feel that way :)